# Dapper: Not able to parse string from dbf(Error parsing column)

Tags: c#, dapper, dbf

I want to use dapper to query over dbf files. In my file example.dbf I have two columns:

1. Value - type NUMERIC
2. Name - type CHARACTER

I write class ExampleDbf

```
class ExampleDbf
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to write two simple query

```
var listOne = connection.Query<ExampleDbf>("SELECT value FROM Example");
var listTwo = connection.Query<ExampleDbf>("SELECT name, value FROM Example");
```

ListOne are OK but when I execute listTwo I Have following System.Data.DataException:

```
Additional information: Error parsing column 0 (name=System.Byte[] - Object)
```

When I use standard DataReader I must write something like that

```
example.name = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])reader["name"]).Trim();
```

Of course I may write something like this:

```
class ExampleDbf2
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public byte[] Name { get; set; }
    public string StringName
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])Name ).Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

So now it works

```
var listTwo = connection.Query<ExampleDbf2>("SELECT name, value FROM Example");
```

But this solution is very ugly, maybe someone have better solution.

Comment: The data from the DB is character data; dapper isn't ever going to make `Encoding` decisions on your behalf: that's far too unclear a question... you could use a shim property, if you wanted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always return a dynamic, then map it to your object and perform the transformation operation during object initialization.

```
var listTwo = connection.Query<dynamic>("SELECT name, value FROM Example")
    .Select(x => new ExampleDbf 
        { 
            Value = x.value,  
            Name = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])x.name).Trim()
        }).ToList();
```